# Getting string value of indexPath.row

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Whats the difference between these 2 ways to get string value of indexPath.row?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var newString: String = String(indexPath.row)
    var newString2: String = indexPath.row.description)
}
```

Comment: For an Int, there is no difference but using ".description" on many objects has some very different results and will not always be a string conversion of the value. Also, you don't need to define your variable ": String = " in swift if the type can be inferred.

Answer (score 5):

The `description` property is used to represent the content of *any* `NSObject` or any class/struct/enum implementing `Printable` protocol in format of string and though in case of `Int` (`indexPath.row` is `Int`) it returns just string value of number you **should never** use it to convert `Int` to `String`. It is possible that in future versions of Swift `description` property will return something like "Int: [value]".
You should use `String(indexPath.row)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var indexValue :String = String(format: "%d", indexPath.row)
```

convert indexPath into String and Store into indexValue variable.